# Activity recreating after firestore update method

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've been trying to make an app, where after a time of 60 seconds, all the data collected by user input gets updated in firestore's existing data. However, as soon as I call the .update method of firebase, the activity gets recreated and timer starts again and it doesn't move on to the next activity. Its stuck in a loop and after every 60 seconds the activity is just recreating itself again and again. I know its because of the update method because if I comment that particular update method line, the application runs fine and normally as it should i.e after 60 seconds the app starts next activity. Also, I'm using firestore listener to get data only once and not real time update listener. I still don't get why is it happening. Please help

Edit:

```
new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long l) {
            roundTimerView.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
            counter--;
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            
            newPlayerData.cards = cards;

            GamePage.this.finish();

            Intent intent = new Intent(GamePage.this,NextRoundReady.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("USERNAME",Username);
            bundle.putString("ROOMID",RoomID);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(intent);

            cr.document(RoomID).update(Username,newPlayerData);
        }
    }.start();
```

cr.document.update is the one giving me trouble, if I comment it out, after timer runs out, next activity starts, but if I uncomment it, after timer ends, it will just recreate the activity and run in a loop

Comment: some code snippet, please.

Comment: Please provide the code that produces this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly `GamePage.this.finish()` seems suspicious, what happens if you remove that?

What happens when you remove startActivity?

The update method shouldn't be the real problem, unless it causes an exception which might restart the app

Also try doing the update before starting the new activity

Comment: I added that finish method to end this activity, just a try to see what happens, but it doesn't end. As for update method I even tried putting it before starting new activity, but it doesn't work. Putting it after calling startActivity, opens new activity but it comes back to this activity in 1 second. If I remove start activity it runs in loop as usual. Only when I comment that update line, the app runs fine. Or else it just runs in loop